# Java API that can convert Excel Sheet into Database Table

Tags: java, database, api, import-from-excel

Is there any APIs available in Java that can convert an Excel Sheet into a database table?
And also for drawing charts and graphs?

Comment: It will be a two step process. Step 1 is to convert the Excel Sheet into data you can use and Step 2 will be loading that data into the database. As a general rule of thumb, you should define your database tables ahead of time instead of dynamically generating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) project to read Excel documents.

Answer (score 4):

A first step could be the [POI project of Apache](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html). 
For graphdrawing, I used to use the [Pefuse Framework](http://prefuse.org/).

Answer (score 2):

XLSQL

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlsql/

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [this](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), but just Google it because there are many options for manipulating excel sheets with java.